# On an Azure DevOps self hosted agent to use Visual Studio you must buy a paid license for that agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

When you have a self-hosted agent on Azure DevOps is common the need to install Visual Studio just only to build your projects. You could use a community license or must install a paid version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a license you just need the build tools which you can find at this link. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16

Comment: OMG that's great! I asked exactly the same on https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/13784 and they just closed my question ¬¬
StackOverflow always to the rescue 
Thanks!